# How do I web scrape JavaScript generated contents?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape everything under "Notes to Financial Statements". How can I do that? This is the link of the webpage: [Please Click](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-18-000145&xbrl_type=v#)

This is the screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

Each item under "Notes to Financial Statements" is generated after I click the link. I want to get the source of each item and parse it, for example, "Summary of Significant Accounting Policies.

Thank you!

Updated: 2019-10-22

Now my question boils down to how can I extract the IDs (i.e., r9, r10, etc.) from the following. It is in one of the

s whose class = "accordion". There is a href="#" id="menu_cat2" in the

.

Not the best code. This is how I managed to do it:

```
   lis = soup.select("li.accordion")
   notes = [str(li) for li in lis if "menu_cat3" in str(li)]
   ids = re.findall(r'id="(r\d+)"', notes[0])
```

[image: source]

Comment: You’ll want to use a package like `html.parser` to extract the hyperlinks in this page’s collection of `a` tags, and visit the ones corresponding to ‘Notes to Financial Statements’ with a package like `resquests`

Comment: The problem is that the link is dynamically generated,href = "#"

Comment: There are a lot of questions on SO about this. Try searching again. Look into scrapy or selenium.

Comment: Use Selenium...is for the Kind Thing you want make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page makes requests based on the ids of the lis in that section. Gather the ids, convert to upper case and make the same requests. Requires bs4 4.7.1+

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = s.get('https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-18-000145&xbrl_type=v#')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    urls = [f'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/{i["id"].upper()}.htm' for i in soup.select('li:has(#menu_cat3) .accordion')]

    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        print([i.text for i in soup.select('font')])
```

Comment: This I have useful discoveries from running your code. I printed out the soup (bs(r.content, 'lxml'), and I found that the links are embedded at the beginning. Some examples: reports[0+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/R1.htm";
    reports[1+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/R2.htm";
    reports[2+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/R3.htm";
    reports[3+1] = "/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019318000145/R4.htm";

Comment: According to the later tag, <li class="accordion" id="r10"><a class="xbrlviewer" href="javascript:loadReport(10);" onclick="javascript:highlight(this);">Summary of Significant Accounting Policies</a></li>, the href would be reports[9+1].

Comment: I believe all I need to do is to get the id = "r10" (the reprot number) etc from <li class="accordion">
<a href="#" id="menu_cat3">Notes to Financial Statements</a>
<ul>
<li class="accordion" id="r10"><a class="xbrlviewer" href="javascript:loadReport(10);" onclick="javascript:highlight(this);">Summary of Significant Accounting Policies</a></li>
<li class="accordion" id="r11"><a class="xbrlviewer" href="javascript:loadReport(11);" onclick="javascript:highlight(this);">Financial Instruments</a></li>

Comment: I think I figured it out based on your answer. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

You can use selenium or scrapy 
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html

Approach:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

Navigate to that link
Click on that html element - can be done by using xpath or css selectors
Get the text contents